# Передача данных через XMLHttpRequest в сервлет

Tags: javascript, java, canvas, xmlhttprequest

Как с помощью `XMLHttpRequest` передать на сервер `canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')` и как эти данные принять в сервлете java в `doPost`

У `XMLHttpRequest` есть несколько вариантов отправки данных (гугл в помощь) мне надо передать `canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')` в виде  виде blob, array, файл. Соответственно в сервлете принять. Как принять в сервлете blob? У меня сейчас принимаются нули.

Comment: Так и сделать: отправить с клиента `XMLHttpRequest` и вычитать в сервлете из `request.getInputStream()`.  Что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: как правильно сформировать XMLHttpRequest ? blob? byteArray?  как прочитать request.getInputStream()? читаются нули...   как отпрвить файл - без проблем, а вот canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg') ?

Comment: @Nofate искал варианты , для подобного не нашёл решения..

Comment: удалять коменты, минусовать инкогнито -  это нормально? комент удалили, так и минус заодно б.

Comment: Комментарий был удален как нецензурный.

Comment: А вопрос ваш минусанули, как можно догадаться за низкое качество. Напишите, в вопросе, что вы уже сделали, покажите код, расскажите, в чем затык.

Comment: а вопрос поставлен как надо, Я не хочу ограничевать отвечаюших в вариантах. Гуглить я умею, в комментах я добавил.Если человек не в теме - пусть даже не отвечает. а расписывать, что я сделал- надо десяток статей приложить. тем кому не понятно пусть спросят. те кто приложили руку к заморозке явно не сталкивались с этой проблемой.

Comment: Ну вот я в теме. И пока  не вижу проблему. `canvas.toDataURL` выплюнул вам строку, вы заслали ее в сервлет каким-нибудь $.post, там вынули строку из стрима, отрезали префикс, распаковали из base64 в байты. все.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24416/discussion-between--and-nofate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ок, мне стало интересно, что же там такого невозможного.

Вот js, отправляем `Blob` размером 8 байт:

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", "/uploadtest");
var a = new Uint8Array([0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07]);
var blob = new Blob([a.buffer]);
req.send(blob);
```

Вот сервлет, который читает байты из стрима:

```java
public class UploadTestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ServletInputStream stream = req.getInputStream();

        // замените на любимый способ вычитывания 
        byte[] buf = new byte[128];
        ByteArrayOutputStream bufOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        for(int bytesRead = 0; bytesRead != -1; bytesRead = stream.read(buf)) {
            bufOut.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        byte[] bytes = bufOut.toByteArray();  
   }
}
```

Ну и web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UploadTest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.UploadTestServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadTest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/uploadtest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Как видите все по-старинке на голых родных API. 8 байт пришли. Вам остается только получить `Blob` из `canvas`.

Comment: Разве не надо смотреть возвращаемое значение и крутить `read` в цикле?

Comment: @Qwertiy, надо конечно. Просто тут я знаю что байт придет 8. Это просто proof-of-concept. А для вычитывания стрима у каждого свой любимый способ есть.

Comment: А они обязаны прийти все 8 сразу? Разве не могут по частям?

Comment: @Nofate Ты волшебник!!!! я перепробывал несколько подобных вариантов(5 или более)(приёмной части) все возвращали в buf нули.

Comment: @Qwertiy, обновил, чтобы никого не смущать.

Answer (score 1):

> мне надо передать canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg') в виде "как есть" не преобразовывая в base64

Data uri - это уже base64.

> а виде blob

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob

Comment: СПАСИБО! дельное указание. тут не доглядел., Тогда вопрос несколько изменяется - как принять blob?

Comment: canvas.toBlob ...к сожалению это только ff

Comment: @Вадим, там же полифил есть.

Comment: правильное название кастыль :) . его я и так написал.

Comment: если верить http://habrahabr.ru/post/119694/ (первый комменарий) можно обойтись и без .toDataURL ... только как? @Qwertiy

Comment: @Вадим, кажется, там про внутреннее представление, а не пор извлечение. Хотя не уверен.